# Custom URI to be nested into http url

Tags: http, uri

I'm making a content displaying http application, and have a bunch of content data sources,
like plain file, sqlite db file, and many more others.

It seems best to me to make a URI to easily identify data sources, like many great projects did(SQLAlchemy, zeromq, etc). It's really okay if I just use the [classical URI format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier) like sourcetype://blah/blah, But if I need some debug urls to just display contents(or metadata) of a data source, the debug url would be a mess because of using [http url restricted characters](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm).

So, I want:

**A:** a nice URI schema that can at least describe something like sqlite:///path/to/my/db with absolute file path AND do not use url escaped characters (that much)

OR

**B:** a nice workaround converting sqlite:///path/to/my/db to be displayed in the browser

I don't expect any exact answer, but any advice is welcomed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could try breaking up your source url into it's components and supply them as either request parameters or encoded in the http url's path.

**request parameters**

```
http://me.com/debug?scheme=sqlite&path=/path/to/my/db&netloc=...
```

**encoded in path (assumes you are using limited url components)**

```
http://me.com/debug/<scheme>/<netloc>/<path*>
```

or

```
http://me.com/debug/sqlite//path/to/my/db
```